# ValueError: Missing required argument: client_id

Tags: python, amadeus

Getting error for client ID not sure why it was working but suddenly it stopped. Using python as my language of choice and api that I'm trying to access is **flight offer search**

```
AMADEUS = Client(
    client_id=settings.AMADEUS_CLIENT,
    client_secret=settings.AMADEUS_SECRET
)
```

**Error:**

```
File "D:\templates\<project>\main\api_methods.py", line 5, in <module>
        AMADEUS = Client(
      File "D:\templates\fare\fare\lib\site-packages\amadeus\amadeus.py", line 87, in __init__
        self._initialize_client_credentials(options)
      File "D:\templates\fare\fare\lib\site-packages\amadeus\mixins\validator.py", line 25, in _initialize_client_credentials
        self.client_id = self.__init_required('client_id', options)
      File "D:\templates\fare\fare\lib\site-packages\amadeus\mixins\validator.py", line 65, in __init_required
        raise ValueError('Missing required argument: {0}'.format(key))
    ValueError: Missing required argument: client_id
```

can you provide some suggestions how to fix it.
**amadeus version : 6.0.1**

Comment: Can you add more details about your code. It looks like you are missing some parameter to initialize the client. Your error is inisde `self.initialize_client_credentials` can you add that code into your post ?

Comment: @EnriqueBet self.initialize_client_credentials  is inbuilt method of amadeus lib.

Comment: Did you add the client ID and the secret to `settings`?

Comment: @vineetsingh can you please give more details about your code?

Comment: This is resolved actually issue was with .env file , thanks for your support .